# How to remove all of the divs? with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom, grid

When I want to change the grid, I want the old one to disappear but right now the old one is being added to the new one. So how to remove all of the old divs? https://codepen.io/diana-larussa/pen/RwGMxqL

````
    if (gridDOMElement.value === 'second') {
        const elementsCount = 36

        for (let index = 0; index < elementsCount; index++) {
            const div = document.createElement("div")
            container.appendChild(div)
        }

        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(6, 7vmax)"
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(6, 7vmax)"
    }

    if (gridDOMElement.value === "third") {
        const elementsCount = 70

        for (let index = 0; index < elementsCount; index++) {
            const div = document.createElement("div")
            container.appendChild(div)
        }

        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(10, 7vmax)"
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(7, 7vmax)"
    }

}

document.querySelector("#grid").addEventListener("change", newGrid)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I added this inside of the newGrid() function and it helped:

```
const item = document.querySelector('.container')
while (item.firstChild) {
    item.removeChild(item.firstChild)
}
```